# Query result printing in categorized list

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, union

```
<?php

require_once('../lankain.php');

if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {

    $queryString = $dbc->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);

    if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
        //$query = $dbc->query("SELECT subjects FROM subject WHERE subjects LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");
        $q = "SELECT keyword, col 
                FROM (
                    SELECT tutor_name AS keyword, 'Tutors' col FROM tutors
                    UNION
                    SELECT subjects AS keyword, 'Subject' col FROM subject
                    UNION
                    SELECT city_name AS keyword, 'City' col FROM city
                    UNION
                    SELECT institute_name AS keyword, 'Institute' col FROM institutes
                ) s
              WHERE keyword LIKE '%$queryString%' 
              LIMIT 10";

        $r = mysqli_query ( $dbc, $q);

        if($q) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

            $col = $row['col'];


        }
        } else {
            echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
        }
    } else {

    }
} else {
    echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
}

?>
```

My query only select subjects, tutor names, institutes and city not selecting category names. Now I need to add category name according to the result set..

can I know is it possible to do with php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT col, keyword
FROM (SELECT tname AS keyword, 'Tutors' col FROM t
      UNION
      SELECT sname AS keyword, 'Subjects' col FROM sub
      UNION
      SELECT cname AS keyword, 'City' col FROM c
      UNION
      SELECT iname AS keyword, 'Institutes' col FROM i
    ) AS s
WHERE keyword LIKE '%$queryString%' 
LIMIT 10
```

How do you want category mapped with result set?

Comment: This logic is working.. But problem is how can I print the result set with above stylized format?

Comment: That thing you can easily do with programming. It will be easier to implement rather than do with query.

Comment: This list I use to display jquery autocomplete box. now I'd like the results from the autocomplete function to be separated into categories..

Comment: My problem is auto complete box display all values of subjects, tutor names, institutes names, city together. Thats why I need to display results from the autocomplete function to be separated into categories. For example, if a user starts typing "an", the autocomplete will show 4 categories with items in each. if a user wants to select one of the items in the list under category "Subject" or "Tutor" or "city" or "institute". what I am trying to do is something similar to facebook search option..

Comment: Use col column to serach data by catogary

Comment: sorry I am not clear with it.. can you elaborate it with an example... Thank you

Comment: Add case statement in while loop for col = subject or col = tutors etc.. and add specific li tags. You have 5 cases are: all, subjects, tutors, cities, institutes.

Comment: I tried it with case statements (see my question) I updated it. But problem is now display category name in all result set in the list.. For example subjects maths, subjects science, subject Muslim ect.. how can I avoid from this issue?

Comment: Simply do not display category. remove that li tag.

Comment: But I need to display category name at once and then items to that category. something similar to my question's list that I have displayed.

Comment: Put it to outside of your while loop

Comment: what did you update? ok.. now it working. I add some logic to compare the current category name with the previous category name.. @Saharsh Shah Thank you very much for your help..